# Homomorphism of quasi coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

I was trying to solve the problems of Liu's book and wanted to show that if both $F$ ,$G$ are coherent then $Hom(F,G)$ is also coherent... but I realised that I really need to understand the meaning and definition of the sheaf of homomorphisms.... so I was tryinng to understand these:

Let $X$ be a scheme, $F$, $G$ two quasi-coherent $O_X$-modules and $U=\operatorname{Spec} A$ be an affine open subset of $X$. Suppose that
$F|_U =\widetilde{M}$ and $G|_U=\widetilde{N}$.
I really need some help to show if $\mathcal{Hom}_U(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)^\sim$

Is $\mathcal{Hom}(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{N})$ also a quasi coherent sheaf?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Next, your typesetting in this problem has some issues. Would you like some help with that?

Comment: Hi, thanks  I couldn't write tild notation so I had to use * instead......

Comment: I've fixed the formatting issues - please check to make sure I did not alter your meaning. You still have a good amount of work to do on this post before it meets our standards here on this website, though. As per my previous comment, please add more context to this post, like where you encountered this problem and what your thoughts are.

Comment: Thanks alot. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Hom_U(\tilde{M},\tilde{N})$ identifies naturally with $Hom_A(M,N)$. Indeed, given $f : \tilde{M} \rightarrow \tilde{N}$, its action on the global sections is a $A$-linear map $M \rightarrow N$. Conversely, given $g: M \rightarrow N$, we can consider the maps $g_{D(a)}: M_a=\tilde{M}(D(a)) \rightarrow N_a=\tilde{N}(D(a))$ which are the localizations of $g$ at $a$; they do glue together to form a sheaf morphism $\tilde{g}: \tilde{M} \rightarrow \tilde{N}$.

Now, let $H$ be the sheaf which is the internal Hom of $\tilde{M}$ and $\tilde{N}$ over $U$. By definition, if $V \subset U$ is principal (ie is $D(a)$), $H(V)$ is the set of homomorphisms $\tilde{M}_{|V} \rightarrow \tilde{N}_{|V}$, so by the above identifies with the set of homomorphisms $\tilde{M}(V) \rightarrow \tilde{N}(V)$, ie of homomorphisms $M_a \rightarrow N_a$. However, $\tilde{Hom_A(M,N)}(V)$ is $Hom(M,N) \otimes \mathcal{O}(V)=Hom(M,N)_a$.

The question thus becomes: how to compare $Hom(M,N)_a$ and $Hom(M_a,N_a)$?

It’s easy to see that we have a $A$-linear map $Hom(M,N)_a \rightarrow Hom(M_a,N_a)$.

You can check that this map is injective if $M$ is finitely generated – and that it isn’t in general if $M$ isn’t (hint: consider the case $M,N$ free). It is bijective if $M$ is free.

If we have an exact sequence $A^m \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ (ie $M$ finitely presented) then we have a natural morphism between the exact sequences $$0 \rightarrow Hom(M,N)_a \rightarrow Hom(A^n,N)_a \rightarrow Hom(A^m,N)_a$$ and $$0 \rightarrow Hom(M_a,N_a) \rightarrow Hom((A_a)^n,N_a) \rightarrow Hom((A_a)^m,N_a).$$

The two rightmost vertical arrows are isomorphisms, so $Hom(M,N)_a \rightarrow Hom(M_a, N_a)$ is an isomorphism.

As a conclusion, the inner Hom of $\tilde{M},\tilde{N}$ is equal to $\tilde{Hom_A(M,N)}$ when $M$ is finitely presented. When $M$ is only finitely generated, the latter is a subsheaf of the former.